# Jupyter notebooks of Pycharm professional is not autofill after using TAB just like normal Jupyter notebook

Tags: pycharm, anaconda, jupyter, autofill

Pycharm professional Jupyter notebooks is not auto-fill after using "TAB" just like normal Jupyter notebook. This normal Jupyter notebook is which came from Anaconda distribution.

Comment: Why did you use the tag [visual-build-professional]?

Comment: Sorry. It is a mistake

Comment: That's okay, thanks!

Comment: You might want to edit your question to add more details... I would describe what happens normally (when tab works) and then the exact scenario when it fails. You're more likely to get responses to your question that way...